Editing APK to Fix Error - No Matching ABIS
I am a complete newbie at attempting to edit an APK, please excuse my lack of knowledge.  I have several old APKs.  I am trying to install it using an adb command at a command prompt with my Samsung S24 connected to my computer via cable (with Developer Mode Enabled and debugging turned on).
When I do this I get this error:  "Install failed no matching ABIS: Failed to extract native libraries, res=113".  I've tried to research this error and I think it is happening because the app isn't written for 64 bit architecture.  I had thought I needed to add info to the Lib files to support 64 bit (by adding a arm64-v8a folder - the Lib folder has an "armeabi" folder).  So I don't know if I'm assessing the situation correctly or not.  Also, I have no clue how to go about all of this.  I have downloaded Android Editor Studio (I can see how to open the file and see the contents) as well as Android Studio.  In Android Studio I only know how to open the apk for debugging (not for editing). Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

The error message means that the apps contain .so files that do not match the CPU of your new phone. Most likely the apps support only armv7 (arm 32 bit) but your new phone can only execute armv8a (arm 64 bit). This problem can not be fixed as you would need identical .so files just for a different architecture. Even for the app developer itself this would be a challenge.
